# Dynamic SELECT TAG filled from MYSQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have problem. I need make dynamic SELECT tag where OPTIONS are filled dynamically from mySQL DB. I have this code but it doesnt work. So if you have some corrects or idea how to make it other way I will be very thankuf:) Thanks alot!

```
<SELECT>
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456");
mysql_select_db("aplikace",$con);
$result = ("SELECT * kod FROM protokoly".
"ORDER BY kod");
$rs = mysql_query($result);
$nr = mysql_num_rows($rs);
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) {
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"".$r["kod"]."\">".$r["kod"]."</OPTION>";
}
?>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Guessing right away it is because you have no space before the `ORDER BY`.  `$result = ("SELECT * kod FROM protokoly ORDER BY kod");` Put it all in one line instead of breaking over the concatenation.

Comment: The mysql_* functions are depreciated, please look into using PDO or mysqli

Comment: I assume by `SELECT * kod FROM protokoly`, you really want `SELECT kod FROM protokoly`. Get rid of the `*` or the `kod`, but don't keep both.

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael Berkowski suggested in a comment, there's not currently a space between `protokoly` and `ORDER BY`. This will result in a MySQL error, but you're not seeing the error which makes it difficult to troubleshoot.

You could modify your code to output an error if one occurs, like this:

```
$rs = mysql_query($result) or die('Error during query: ' . mysql_error());
```

If `mysql_query()` fails, [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) with a call to `mysql_error()` will output the contents of the most recent MySQL error, helping you to catch the problem.

**Edit:**

To illustrate the usage of `die()` I've edited your code as follows:

```
<?php
// Place at top of file
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>

<SELECT>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aplikace", $con) or die('Cannot select database: ' . mysql_error());
$result = ("SELECT * kod FROM protokoly ORDER BY kod");
$rs = mysql_query($result) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$nr = mysql_num_rows($rs) or die('Failed to get num_rows: ' . mysql_error());
for ($i = 0; $i < $nr; $i++)
{
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"{$r['kod']}\">{$r['kod']}</OPTION>";
}
?>
</SELECT>
```

Note that statements using `mysql_...()` functions include `mysql_error()` inside `die()` so that any MySQL error will be output. I've also enclosed array references in brackets within a double-quoted string on the echo statement to simplify it and eliminate multiple concatenation.

Comment: I updated the code $rs = mysql_query($result) or die('Error during query: ' . mysql_error()); but no error displayed and SELECT is still empty:/

Comment: Make sure your php.ini file is set to show errors, or alternately use `error_reporting()` and `ini_set()` at runtime: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: other errors are displaying me correctly but this no, php.ini is configured

Comment: You can add `or die()` to other lines of code in search of what's failing. Hopefully that is of help to you.

Comment: i add 'or die()' almost on each line of php but still no error ocured:/  [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35284336/err.PNG) screen of code displaye in Chrome

Comment: I linked the php manual page for `die()` in the answer. You'll want to include something for it to output if it gets called. For example `die(mysql_error())` or `die('$x was ' . $x);`

Comment: i dont know how do you mean that.If you will be so kind and try to edit my code to work it good please:)

Comment: yes it now works correctly, thanks a lot i have had some syntax errors:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<SELECT>
<?php

//added error checking.
if (!($con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456")))
{
    die("Could not connect to database server. " . mysql_errno() . " => " . mysql_error());
}

//added error checking.
if (!mysql_select_db("aplikace",$con))
{
    die("Could not select database. " . mysql_errno() . " => " . mysql_error());
}

//removed *, pushed ORDER BY onto same line
$sql = "SELECT kod FROM protokoly ORDER BY kod";

//added error checking. added connection parameter
if (!($rs = mysql_query($sql,$con)))
{
    die("Could not execute query. " . mysql_errno() . " => " . mysql_error());
}

//added condition
if (($nr = mysql_num_rows($rs)) == 0)
{
    die("No options to give!");
}

//changed to while loop that checks result of function return
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    //changed " to ' to get rid of \"
    echo '<OPTION VALUE="' . $r["kod"] . '">' . $r["kod"] . '</OPTION>';
}
?>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: thank you so much!:) but still it is not working corectly this is a SCREEN [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35284336/errr.PNG) no data from MYSQL are displayed

Comment: @forgatn it looks like you are displaying the name of the variable, rather than the contents of the variable. You may have missplaced or forgotten an escaped quotation mark somewhere. Anyway, check out the chnages to my answer. I changed the `"` to `'` to get rid of the required escapes.

Comment: yes, i tried that, but it still doesnt work man:/ i am sending a screen of [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35284336/erorekmagorek.PNG)
i am helpless://

Comment: @forgatn I don't know what to tell you. Did you accidentally insert that value into the database?

Comment: yes, data are in database in column `kod` but it doesnt display them in the select tag:/